# Disable Ambient Lighting(HDRP)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to disable the ambient lighting for my *HDRP* project. However, whatever I do, nothing seems to work. In my lighting section, I am missing the ***ENVIRONMENT*** tab? I also want to enable a custom sky, which I cannot do through an *HDRI* sky override on the *volume* script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know op is probably long gone, but here's what I did to basically remove ambient lighting.

Go to your global volume, under the HDRI sky override, there should be a little dropdown that says intensity mode. Change it to multiply and set the multiply value to 0. Then turn up the exposure. This might not be the best solution though.